# Issue hosting a discord.js v14.3.0 bot on a VPS

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js, vps, pm2

I recently got a VPS to host a discord.js bot of mine. But Ive been getting errors when seeing the [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DJgx.png) from [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) [`pm2 log`] which is resulting in the bot not going online & errors.

Reason why I'm confused here is the template was originally from a [repl.it project](https://replit.com/@4515384697/discord-slash-commands-bot-template?v=1) which worked perfictly fine there, but when I bring it over onto the VPS it starts to have some issues *internally* with the node modules. If you think you know how to resolve this issue lease feel free to pitch some thoughts at me

I'll provide all the versions I'm running below, but if you need more data feel free to reach out

OS: `Ubuntu 20.04 64 Bit`, discordjs: `14.3.0`, npm: `6.14.4`, nodejs: `10.19.0`

Comment: I followed what you said to do and update node to 10.19.0 but I still got the same error..

Answer (score 0):

Discord.js required Node version `16.9.0` or higher as stated in the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome):

> Node.js 16.9.0 or newer is required.

In your question, your Node version was only `10.19.0`. To resolve this issue, you need to update your Node version.